# client server communication using sockets in android two emulators

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I am having an error when trying to connect two android Emulators.

First I run Client Emulator 5554 then SErver Emulator 5556

The other side CMD i write this:

```
telnet localhost 5554
redir add tcp:5000:6000
```

After I click send button in client side I got an error not responding!

My code:

Server

```
package com.example.socketserver;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textIn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void Start(View v) throws IOException{
        Socket socket = null;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);

        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Listening...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TextView label=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        label.setText("Loading...");
        serverSocket.close();
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Client

```
package com.example.socketclient;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);
    }

    public void Send(View v) throws IOException{
        Socket socket = null;
        socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 5000);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Message from Sender");

        if (socket != null){
        socket.close();
        }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.client, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat? Did you put the permissions in the android manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Yes 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: 06-09 17:39:00.827: E/ActivityManager(849): 13% TOTAL: 6.8% user + 6.8% kernel